# Sum up list of Edit Boxes based on a data type?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of edit boxes with values in them. Some are expenses (type-id="1"), and others are incomes (type-id="2").

They are defined as:

```
<input class="change-handled form-control" type-id="@sub.CategoryTypeId" sub-category-id="@sub.SubCategoryId" data-id="@sub.CategoryBudgetId" style="text-align: right; width: 100%" type="number" value="@(sub.BudgetAmount.HasValue ? sub.BudgetAmount.ToString() : "")" />
```

At the moment, I have a javascript function which sums them all up, and displays the total:

```
var total = 0;
        var $changeInputs = $('input.change-handled');
        $changeInputs.each(function (idx, el) {
                total += Number($(el).val());
        });
        $('#budgettedValue').text(total.toFixed(2));
```

This works. However, I need to display a total for expenses, and a total for income.

So, I was hoping it would be as easy as this:

```
var total = 0;
        var $changeInputs = $('input.change-handled');
        $changeInputs.each(function (idx, el) {
            if ($(idx).attr('type-id') == 1) {
                totalExp += Number($(el).val());
            }
            if ($(idx).attr('type-id') == 2) {
                totalInc += Number($(el).val());
            }
        });
```

This, doesn't work. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're wrapping index `idx` with jQuery, when you're accessing `attr`. Instead use `el` which is the element.

Also you don't need two `if`s, since if one is not of type `1`, then it must be of type `2`

```
$changeInputs.each(function (idx, el) {
   if ($(el).attr('type-id') == '1')
     totalExp += Number($(el).val());
   else  
     totalInc += Number($(el).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure what the parameters (idx, el) mean. Are they index (of the element) and element (pointer to the actual element)?